# CompletionException:client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 and server side HTTP request parsing errors RFC 7230 and has been ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

In my application I call an external API using RestTemplate post method, but the API doesn't accept my request. It's returning `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400` I am able to access the API via Swagger and Postman. I pass the same value and it's working

Server side I am getting: `Error parsing HTTP request header Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level does not conform to RFC 7230 and has been ignored.`

my pgm below

```
 HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + "wwwwwwwwwww");
 httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
 httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*/*");
 httpHeaders.set("key","value");// this is dummy value for this forum
 restTemplate.exchange(join("http://", localhost:9898, "/testData"), POST,
                                    new HttpEntity<>(requestObj.toString(), httpHeaders), String.class)
```

Comment: HTTP 400 means bad request. Perhaps you should not call toString on the request object?

Comment: my server api request as request body only ... but same working in postman and swagger. its not working in resttemplate only

Comment: To this work, your to string method might converting to json or xml, or the server expects a plain text as requests(which is unusual)

Comment: without this httpHeaders.set("key","value");// this is dummy value for this forum
i am able to access server . i dont know why its giving like this

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are sending the exact same request with Swagger or Postman? It looks like the API returns an error because it doesn't support the header you are sending it. The problem could be the header key or the value, or both. Does it work if you keep the same header key, but with a different header value? Checking the APIs documentation could also help.

Comment: yes it  is problem with header key value only . httpHeaders.set("key","value");  this value in header my code working fine . but why its not accepting my customized header

Comment: What is the output of requestObj.toString()? If this is a "standard" toString() implementation it will not be JSON. If your requestObj class is well designed you should be able to set the requestObj as the entity body. It will then be serialized to JSON automatically. Also, is "key", "value" a good representation of the real header key and values? Or are the real key and value different in some way that might violate header constraints?

Comment: my code working fine before adding the httpHeaders.set("key","value");  for some purpose I need to add the httpHeaders.set("key","value") key is the its kind of uuid and value is uuid value . can you tell how to log this . I know this header only the problem . while go to server API it will given parsing exception